# App does not run on device anymore... freaking out

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

out of nowhere I started getting the following error when I tried to run: Xcode, Duplicate symbol _main

So I read on another post that the solution was to remove the items from targets -> compile sources

Now it will run on the simulator only. It first starts to load on the build bar but once it gets to about 10%, it stops and stays like that for 20 seconds and then say build Succeeded  (no errors) but won't ever launch onto my iOS device. Been trying to figure out whats going on for the last 2 hours. Can someone please help me?

Thank you so much

Comment: What kind of device, which version of iOS on the simulator/device?

Comment: @AndreasLey iphone 4, iOS 5.1

Answer (score 1):

If it runs on the simulator then it doesn't seem to be a problem with the code.

Although I've never encountered this particular error, a lot of XCode's problems can be solved by disconnecting the device, deleting the app on the device, restarting the device.

Comment: I tried that an no luck. I really think it has to do with the fact I deleted everything from compile sources:(

Comment: If you change the compile sources back to what they were (typically 'According to file type') and then clean/disconnect/delete/restart does the error come back? If so, do you in fact have main() declared twice?

Comment: what do you mean? I remember there were like 119 files in the compile sources I believe. How would I change them back? Thanks

Comment: Maybe we're not talking about the same thing, did you remove the settings under 'Compile Sources As' on the 'Build Settings' tab under Targets? Or did you remove all your source files from the project? If so, you could re-add them via the menu with 'File'>'Add Files to "ProjectName"...'.

Comment: The first option. I remembering seeing double main.m and other of my files but for some reason I was an idiot and deleted them all instead of double main.m... Thanks

Comment: I've checked various of my own projects and all of them have just two options there, 'Debug' and 'Release', both of them set to 'According to File Type'. You could set it to that and see if it works. If it doesn't I'm afraid I can't help further, that would be a configuration I'm not familiar with.

Comment: sorry I'm not getting this but I don't see this. If you go under "targets" in your project and then "build phases", then you should see "compile sources". Are we talking about the same thing? Thanks

Comment: Ah, no, the setting I mentioned is under the 'Build settings' tab, not 'Build phases'. If you click on the + button you should get a dialog with the option to re-add files that are in your project; select all files with .m extension.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11410/discussion-between-alex-g-and-stuart)